# Please explain this integration equation

Tags: calculus, integration

For $-1<x<1$,

$$\int_{0}^{-x}\frac{t^n}{1-t}dt=\int_{0}^{x}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{t^n}{1+t}dt$$

My derivation:

$$\int_{0}^{-x}\frac{t^n}{1-t}dt=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(-1\cdot{}t)^{n}}{1-(-t)}(-dt)=\int_{0}^{x}(-1)^{n}\frac{t^n}{1+t}\cdot{}(-1)dt=\int_{0}^{x}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{t^n}{1+t}dt$$

Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct. It's basically the equivalent of using substitution, like $u = -t, du = -dt$, so $dt = -du$, and then adjusting the limits of integration so they match, with this leaving the lower limit at $0$ as the negative is still $0$, and changing the upper limit from $-x$ to $x$. This then gives

$$\int_{0}^{x} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{u^n}{1 + u} du \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

At the end, since $u$ is just a dummy variable used for integration, it's changed back to $t$.